# Unable to get table alias working with spring jdbcTemplate

Tags: spring, spring-jdbc

I am trying select statement on a table with alias name. When I retrieve the resultset the alias doesn't seem to work with `it.item_id`. It works with `item_id`. Any idea where I am going wrong?

```
getJdbcTemplate().query((connection) -> {
            PreparedStatement preparedStatement = connection.prepareStatement("SELECT * FROM some_item_table AS it WHERE it.item_id = ?");
            preparedStatement.setString(1, 123);
            return preparedStatement;
        }, (rs, i) -> product()
                .setId(rs.getInt("it.item_id"))// NOT WORKING
                //.setId(rs.getInt("item_id")) THIS WORKS!
                ...
                );
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the result set the aliases are not available so it does not work.

You could change your SQL query like `SELECT it.item_id AS some_item_id * FROM some_item_table AS it` then you can do `rs.getInt("some_item_id")`.

In your query you do not really need an alias as you have only one table.

Comment: I believe the `*` in `SELECT it.item_id AS some_item_id *` is to select all columns and use `some_item_id` alias? I am using sybase as the underlying db. It doesn't seem to recognise `*` ,although it recognise `SELECT it.item_id AS some_item_id`

Answer (score 0):

For some databases, you will have to include a comma for it to recognise the * like   `SELECT it.item_id AS some_item_id, * FROM some_item_table AS it`